# api gateway endpoint with cognito authorizer cros error?

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using API gateway with cognito for Authorizae a GET endpoint.
if I am running it through postman(node\python code) it works great.
**BUT when i am running through a react app in CHROME i get**
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my path' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Details over my api gateway API

1. GET request with cognito authorizaer with expect a `Authorization` header
2. The get request has lambda proxy that return the following header

```
"headers": {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, GET, POST',
        },
```

3. OPTIONS method wihtout cognito authorizer
4. I enable CORS on the endpoint.

result:

1. without cognito on the GET it works -> i get content into my react app
2. the moment i add cognito auth i get CORS error
3. the Exception i see when running `curl -v -X OPTIONS https://<mypath>` is

```
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 401 
< date: Mon, 26 Apr 2021 08:03:37 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 26
< x-amzn-requestid: 5f305d7d-70cc-4751-81f5-581345521f00
< x-amzn-errortype: UnauthorizedException
< x-amz-apigw-id: eYcKEHB2vHcFSLw=
<
```

4. the react code i am running is:

```
import axios from "axios";
const value = <my id token>
const url1 = "https:...."
const headers ={
  "Authorization": value,
}
function getPoints(){
   axios.get(
    url1, headers
  ).then((response) => {
    console.log("sucessssssss");
    console.log(response)
    // console.log(response.json());
  }, (error) => {
    console.log("errorrrrr");
    console.log(error);
  }); 
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getPoints()}
      cors test
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong? any help\hint would help
thx

Comment: Getting 401 (Unauthorized) in the curl OPTIONS response suggests the API Gateway endpoint is not configured for CORS correctly. I'd delete your OPTIONS config and add the default via the AWS console Actions menu until it works. Browsers can't send auth for OPTIONS. Until curl OPTIONS returns 200, it's not likely to work. 401 suggests auth for OPTIONS is set to something other than NONE. As a separate matter, the auth header in your code example seems to be missing the Bearer prefix for the token, e.g. `"Authorization": "Bearer " + value` (space between Bearer and token)

Comment: Additionally, you can still see a misleading 401 for OPTIONS in API Gateway if there's no OPTIONS verb configured at all. That makes it look like it's misconfigured to require auth, but it's actually just not enabled. Is it possible that you added an OPTIONS config to the API but forgot to deploy it to your stage endpoint? (i.e. you see it in the console for the API, but it's not visible in the Stages section of the console)

Answer (score 1):

The CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-*`) are response headers. You shouldn't specify them in your request.

API Gateway has an [out-of-the-box CORS handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) that you should use.

If you decide you still want to use your own handler, ensure that if you are setting your Cognito authorizer as the default authorizer, that you *explicitly* set the Authorizer on your `OPTIONS` method to the `NONE` authorizer.

Comment: But pay attention to what I wrote, on the options there is no cognito authorization

Comment: My apologies, what confused me was this: "without cognito it works, and i get content into my react app the moment i add cognito auth i get CORS error any ideas what i am doing wrong?"

Comment: Updated. You must return the appropriate header in your get and post handler on top of your options handler.

Comment: but as you see my returned header is ``` 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ```

Comment: I've updated with a couple of points but this isn't complicated stuff and if really don't have an authorizer set and your options handler is being correctly invoked and responding correctly then there isn't a clear reason why it doesn;t work. Do doublecheck everything you stated is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help out any other poor souls in CORS hell:

API Gateway must be configured to use no Authorization for the `OPTIONS` request.  You should have a configuration for your resource that looks something like:

[image: required method definitions for CORS]

In your CORS settings you'll want to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` if you need to pass an `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thats works as a charm! Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this: When you log in to get the session, you should use session.idToken.jwtToken instead of session.accessToken.jwtToken